ComponentWillUnmount method is never called
I'm developing a simple react app with the following pages:
export default class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar... />
        <Switch>
           ...
          <Route
            exact
            path="/project"
            render={(props) => (
              <Project .../>
            )}
          />
      ...
    )
  }
}

I want to detect every time a user exits the project component, to do some logic. I've tried to use the `componentWillUnmount` method as follow:

```jsx
class Project extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log("hello, world!")
  }

  ...
}

Problem is that componentWillUnmount method is never called when I try to refresh the page, change URL etc, any hints?
react version: ^18.3.1
react router version: 5.2.0


FWIW since you are using React 18 and React-Router v5 you should bump to at least react-router@5.3.4 to avoid routing/navigation issues. See my answer  here for details.

Thanks, I'm updating right now. ;)

Reloading the page basically means "dump the current page" and reload, the React app and components don't have an opportunity to unmount. You could likely utilize a beforeunload listener to run some logic in the case the user reloads the entire page or the page unloads for any other reason (like they navigate completely out of your app, to another domain/page, etc.).
class Project extends Component {
  ...

  // unload event callback handler
  unloadHandler = () => {
    console.log("hello, world!");
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // instantiate unload event listener
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.unloadHandler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // remove unload event listener when component just unmounts
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.unloadHandler);

    // manually call handler to run the same logic
    this.unloadHandler();
  }

  ...
}

